# How to deal with repeated letters in arabic

Tags: python, arabic

I want to normalize arabic string by replacing repeated characters with only one character. For example: the word

```
 رااااائع
```

will be normalized as

```
رائع
```

I found a regular expression suitable for english (python):

```
s="I loooooooooooooooooove  you" 
s = re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', s) // s= "I love you"
```

But, this regular expression does not work for arabic strings. I don't undertand the cause. I'm wondering if anyone could help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import itertools
string = u"رااااائع"
''.join(char for char, _ in itertools.groupby(string))
```

I can't test it with arabic but it works with normal strings

reference: [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: The code doesn't work. the string "رااااائع" remains as it is

Comment: printing gives me رائع

Comment: Ye thats what i found out, the u before the string makes it unicode, fixing it

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line to your code :
`from __future__ import unicode_literals`

```
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import re
s="رااااائع"

s = re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', s)
print s
```

Out put :

```
رائع
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting a character that cannot be converted to utf-8.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

I suggest you use either ignore or replace:

```
v= var.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

or:

```
v= var.encode('utf-8', 'replace')
```

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: I still have the same error with the two options 'ignore' and 'replace'

Comment: I tried replicating your code, mine works and converts رااااائع gracefully without the need to ignore nor replace any character. Would you please update your question and maybe post a snippet of the file contents?